# What is the most suitable Java data structure for representing JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, data-structures

I' m developing a RESTful Android mobile client. Information exchange between my app and server is in JSON. So I' m now a little bit confused what data structure choose for represent JSON responses and data because there a lot of them. I've just stopped with LinkedHashMap<> but as far as i know JSON is unordered. Across the Internet I saw people use Map<> or HashMap<> for this.

So the question - what is the best data structure for this purpose? Or if there is no a univocal answer - pros and cons of using data structures I' ve mentioned.

Comment: JSON is a mixture of "objects", "arrays", and primitive types.  For the most part a flavor of Map works for "objects" and an ArrayList works for the arrays.  But many JSON implementations in Java provide their own classes (for good/bad reasons).

Comment: Conceptually you would be hard-pressed to find any JSON library that could not deserialize any JSON input into a `Map<String, Object>`. The `Object` value could be any one of an autoboxed primitive, a List, or another Map. Not necessarily the easiest data structure to work with though - I highly recommend building a real object model with POJO's.

Comment: I would recommend using a library to deserialize the json into POJOs. [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) works great on Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would disagree with the first answer. The REST paradigm was developed so that you would operate with objects, rather than operations.

For me the most sensible approach will be if you declare beans on the client side and parse the json responses and request through them. I would recommend using the [GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for the serialization/ deserialization. `JsonObject`/ `JsonArray` is almost never the best choice.

Maybe if you give examples of the operations you are about to use we might be able to help more precisely.

**EDIT:** Let me also give a few GSON Examples. Let's use this thread to compare the different libraries.

In the most cases REST services communicate objects. Let's assume you make a post of product, which has reference to shop.

```
{ "name": "Bread",
  "price": 0.78,
  "produced": "08-12-2012 14:34",
  "shop": {
     "name": "neighbourhood bakery"
  }
}
```

Then if you declare the following beans:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private Date produced;
    private Shop shop;
    // Optional Getters and setters. GSON uses reflection, it doesn't need them
    // However, better declare them so that you can access the fields
}

public class Shop {
   private String name;
    // Optional Getters and setters. GSON uses reflection, it doesn't need them
    // However, better declare them so that you can access the fields
}
```

You can deserialize the json using:

```
String jsonString; // initialized as you can
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"); // setting custom date format
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Product product = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Product.class);
// Do whatever you want with the object it has its fields loaded from the json
```

On the other hand you can serialize to json even more easily:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"); // setting custom date format
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(product);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about receiving and parsing the JSON string from a server request?

For that you can use:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Using these, I read through my JSON array from my POST request and store the resulting information in Class objects in my project.

For each item in JSONArray, you can extract the JSONObject and attributes like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    jsonObject.getString("text");
}
```

As far as actually storing the data, like mentioned above, JSON data can come in a wide array of formats depending on the source, and as such, it is usually parsed on the client end and saved in your application Class objects for use. Or more generically, you could store the data using `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 1):

This is easily the best answer I've seen:

https://dzone.com/articles/which-is-the-right-java-abstraction-for-json

Summary: there are three abstrations: pojos, maps and lists, and custom classes to represent objects, arrays, and primitives. There are advantages and disadvantages to each, with no clear winner.

Pojos have the biggest advantages, but you can't always use them. Use them if you can, and use the others if you must.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing anything other than the most simple mapping then you should use a full class structure.  Create your class hierarchy as a mirror of the data structure in JSON and use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) to map the JSON directly to the class hierarchy using the ObjectMapper.

With this solution you don't have any casting of Object to Map or messing around with JSONObject or JSONArray and you don't have any multi-level map traversal in your code. You simply take the JSON string, feed it to the ObjectMapper, and get a your Object, which contains child objects (even collections) automatically mapped by the ObjectMapper.

Comment: so... based on the example in your answer (and the tutorial), you are deserializing to a Product instead of a Map or something like that, which is exactly what I was referring to with the class hierarchy. You have some class hierarchy that includes the class Product (and whatever classes Product uses) so yours is the same answer as mine, just a different tool.

Comment: Yes we have 3 similar tools and one different answer (which i find most unfitting). If I had to compare I would say Gson is faster and easier to use than Jackson. A difference is that Jackson uses getters/setters by default, whilst Gson works with reflection. I wonder what the situation with the tool of @hd1?

Comment: We actually did some performance tests and found jackson considerably faster than gson. Our json was larger (600k+), so with small responses they may be very comparable. We went with gson first and when switching to jackson it was nearly a drop-in replacement, they were both equally easy to use, and orders of magnitude easier to use than JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) to [serialize JSON](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html), in the following way:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
xstream.alias("myAlias", MyClass.class); // requires a no argument constructor
System.out.println(xstream.toXML(product));
```

Ok, the gentleman in the comments wants a deserialization example, here you are:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
xstream.alias("myAlias", MyClass.class);
Product product = (Product)xstream.fromXML(json);
System.out.println(product.getName());
```

Let me know if you need further assistance...

Comment: So what is XStream doing: serialization of Beans to/ from json string? Does it require any additional annotations or anything? Can it deal with nested beans? Does it work on Android? I am asking because I have not heard of this library before.

Comment: The tutorial pointed to in the answer addresses those things. In short, yes, no, yes, and yes.

Comment: I have extended my answer to include examples of the usage of the library I suggest. Would you mind to extend yours as well? I know you point to tutorial, but a short example might be of use, too. I hope we will increase the value of the answers if we do so.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev if you bothered to look at the tutorial, you'd have found your sample code, but I am similarly lazy and have therefore copy-pasted the code above.

Comment: why to/from `Xml`? What is `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver` for? Waht other modes are there?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev The docs for xstream make it look like it's primarily an xml serialization library with json format input/output retrofitted. I've never played with it, but would be interested to see the library size and performance comparison to gson, jackson, and native android json handling code.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev it is what it is. Jettison is another JSON driver and the default is XML. You could write your own, though I've never had the experience.